# How to change Pycharm Python version to Python 3?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently a Python and Pycharm newbie and was practicing some beginner code when I noticed that I was on Python 2.7. Naturally, I wanted to switch to a Python 3 version, but I can't figure out how to make the switch. I've researched online and can get as far as adding a Python interpreter, but then no Python 3 versions show.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Python and PyCharm Setup/Tutorial](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~csci141/Docs/PyCharm-Setup.html) see the section "Configure PyCharm with Python3"

Comment: Do you have Python 3 installed?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if I actually have Python 3 installed. I simply installed Pycharm and began coding. How does one install Python 3?

Comment: @user11666505 I have added an (extremely brief) answer. However, if you want more specific steps, you may need to edit your question to include your general OS information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've researched online and can get as far as adding a Python interpreter, but then no Python 3 versions show. How does one install Python 3?

Vanilla Python 3.x can be downloaded from the [official Python site](https://www.python.org/downloads/). The installers for Windows and Mac should be relatively straightforward.

On Windows, you will probably wish to add `python.exe` to your path variable(s). You may also wish to install the [py](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) Python launcher (this can be selected when using the installer, above). A general overview of installing Python on Windows is available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).

On Linux, you can typically install Python 3 with the package manager for your distribution. Source code versions are also provided on the official website.

---

As a side note, if `python` still uses version 2.7 from the command line, you may either not be using the correct command (e.g. `python3` on Linux) or you may need to edit your path variable(s) (typical on Windows, as noted above). In either case, you do not need to remove Python 2.7. (which, on *Nix-style OSes, may have disastrous consequences).

Comment: > (which, on *Nix-style OSes, may have disastrous consequences). => The Debian / Ubuntu package manager (the main software installation tool) uses Python2  - remove it an see the consequences.