# Pycharm doesn't detect python installed from Microsoft store

Tags: windows-10, path, python3, pycharm, microsoft-store

I have python 3.7 installed on my pc downloaded from python's official website and pycharm detects it and is fine. But, windows's powershell doesn't detect it. I have added it to path of system and tried putting it in user' path too and that didn't work. So, whenever i run 'python' command in powershell, i am always redirected to Microsoft store to download python. So, i downloaded python 3.8 from the store and now my pycharm doesn't detect it (this particular python version can't be seen in "C:/Users/user_name/Appdata/Local/Programs/Python/". I can only see python 3.7 here that i downloaded from website, so i can't give the location of interpretor manually to pycharm.). I want to use some interpretor in both programs. How do i do this.
I am on windows 10 pro 64 bit on a hp bs-145tu.

Comment: "so i can't give the location of interpretor manually to pycharm." - You actually can;  Remove the path for Python 3.7 from the PATH variable and replace it with the path for Python 3.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Pycharm Python version to Python 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/1450222/how-to-change-pycharm-python-version-to-python-3).  The accepted answer to the duplicate indicates the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try running `python3` command in powershell, because you have Python 3 installed in your PC.

And if powershell isn't detecting python as a command then you might have not added it to the environment variable correctly.

Try reinstalling Python3 from Python's website.